# Java/Scala Selenium Appears to Leak Memory

Tags: java, scala, selenium, proxy

I am trying to create a stable system in Linux to do some acquisition in Scala/Java for building databases, analysis; etc using Selenium 3 beta 4.  I see my processes die unexpectedly after 1000 or so runs or become so slow as to barely work using xvfb. As seen below, there does not seem to be a heap space problem. Is there a known issue I cannot find with Google and on Github, some sort of leak in Gecko Driver? I am using Firefox 49 and GeckoDriver 10. Is there an issue running multiple browsers with different proxies in separate threads? How can I resolve this issue while maintaining proxy per browser instance and multiple threads on a single system? Do I need Linux Containers to accomplish this task?

I checked my memory usage but it is below 2 gb. I set xmx at 4g. CPU usage is at 75 %. My need for proxy support eliminates the ability to use tools like grid. I need rotating proxies without adding an extreme degree of complexity at 1 proxy per instance with as uniform a use as possible.

The speed boost from Java is not negligable as I am able to perform fairly decent ETL using threads really quickly. When combining with the Apache Http Async Client Pool I can get 10s of thousands of records in 2NF form with some standardization in a few hours as opposed to a day or two with Python. I tried building a browser in FX as well but a 'minor' Oracle based memory leak with a target resolution seemingly in Java 9 related to media handles kills the process after 20-25 pages. I actually need to process media at times though.

I am setting the settings in Capabilities and in FirefoxProfile:

```
fp = new FirefoxProfile(path)
```

My profile sets the following:

```
fp.setPreference("app.update.auto",false)
fp.setPreference("app.update.enabled",false)
fp.setPreference("app.update.silent",true)
fp.setPreference("xpinstall.customConfirmationUI",false)
fp.setPreference("extensions.updates.enabled",false)
fp.setPreference("extensions.update.autoUpdateDefault",false)
fp.setPreference("extensions.update.enabled",false)
fp.setPreference("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled",false)
fp.setPreference("datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled",false)
```

My proxy settings (1 per browser) are set with the following code:

```
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.type",1)
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http",proxyHost)
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port",proxyPort)
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl",proxyHost)
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port",proxyPort)
fp.setPreference("network.proxy.socks",proxyHost)
fp.setPreference("netowrk.proxy.socks_port",proxyPort)
```

Comment: please, check your dependency tree and check, do you have netty 4.0 or async-http-client 2.0.* in it?

Comment: @Tolsi io.netty:netty:3.5.7.Final.jar

Comment: I don't know really, I have a memory leak due ForkJoinTask[] (I see it with VisualVM in sampler tab) with play 2.5. (netty 4.0.* and async-http-client 2.0.*) ws, but after recompilation with netty 4.1 and async-http-client 2.1 alpha it is gone

Comment: @Tolsi The wierd part for me would be that there is no memory leak at all from the VisualVM. Memory use is well below max, something like 20mb. I know the issue isn't my Apache client because I spent forever getting that to stop leaking memory and it turned out to mostly be JavaFX.